# htaccess not evaluated for one URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have currently a interesting problem with my web server which I cannot find a solution for and hope for your help.

I have set up an Apache server on Arch Linux and I'm using VirtualDocumentRoot for creating "development domains". The configuration file looks like this:

```
ServerName localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    DocumentRoot /srv/http/
    ServerName localhost

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/http/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
    LogLevel warn rewrite:trace3
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /srv/http/%-2/webroot/
    VirtualScriptAlias /srv/http/%-2/cgi-bin/
    DocumentRoot /srv/http/

    ServerAlias *.localhost

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/http/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
    LogLevel warn rewrite:trace3

    LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log vcommon

</VirtualHost>
```

My file structure on the server is build up that way:

```
root folder (/srv/http/)
 |- project folder (e.g. projectname)
     |- some project stuff (e.g. nbproject)
     |- some project stuff (e.g. vendor)
     |- public folder (webroot)
```

So if I access http://localhost it will show me all projects. Clicked on a project I can see all folders and clicked on "webroot" I will see the final homepage of the project.

Because of the VirtualDocumentRoot configuration I can also access http://projectname.localhost directly and it will server the content of /srv/http/projectname/webroot which gives the possiblity to test the webpage like in a "real condition".

For one of these projects I created a MVC system which is build up like e.g. Wordpress. You if you call something like http://projectname.localhost/foo/bar the server should serve the file /srv/http/projectname/webroot/index.php and pass foo and bar as parameters to the index file.
This is done by putting a .htaccess file to the webroot folder which has this content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This works quite well with both versions. So http://localhost/projectname/webroot/foo/bar and http://projectname.localhost/foo/bar provide the exactly same result.

**And now there comes the funny stuff:**

If on this MVC page the user wants to access a non-existing topic he will be redirected to the page http://projectname.localhost/error/404.
But this page cannot be called! Instead of showing the fancy error page I get the servers internal error page. The folder "error" is not existing in real. This is OK since the .htaccess should still serve the index.php. But the .htaccess is not executed.

So I made some tests and had this result (in brackets you can see if redirection worked and the server reply status code):

- http://projectname.localhost/error [OK 200]
- http://projectname.localhost/error/404 [NOK 404]
- http://projectname.localhost/error/?test [NOK 403]
- http://projectname.localhost/error?test [OK 200]
- http://projectname.localhost/something [OK 200]
- http://projectname.localhost/something/404 [OK 200]
- http://projectname.localhost/something/?test [OK 200]
- http://projectname.localhost/something?test [OK 200]
- http://localhost/projectname/webroot/error [OK 200]
- http://localhost/projectname/webroot/error/404 [OK 200]
- http://localhost/projectname/webroot/error/?test [OK 200]
- http://localhost/projectname/webroot/error?test [OK 200]
- http://localhost/projectname/webroot/something [OK 200]
- http://localhost/projectname/webroot/something/404 [OK 200]
- http://localhost/projectname/webroot/something/?test [OK 200]
- http://localhost/projectname/webroot/something?test [OK 200]

The problem ONLY occurs if I use the VirtualDocumentRoot version and the URL sub-path starts with "error" and the path continues somehow.

I checked the log files and for all OKs the access.log looks like this:

```
projectname.localhost 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Oct/2020:06:00:00 +0000] "GET /something/404 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

and the error.log looks like this:

```
[Fri Oct 02 06:00:00.919667 2020] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 80730] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:33272] 127.0.0.1 - - [projectname.localhost/sid#5579881cec50][rid#5579883c5440/initial] [perdir /srv/http/projectname/webroot/] add path info postfix: /srv/http/projectname/webroot/something -> /srv/http/projectname/webroot/something/404
[Fri Oct 02 06:00:00.919721 2020] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 80730] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:33272] 127.0.0.1 - - [projectname.localhost/sid#5579881cec50][rid#5579883c5440/initial] [perdir /srv/http/projectname/webroot/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/http/projectname/webroot/something/404 -> something/404
[Fri Oct 02 06:00:00.919736 2020] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 80730] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:33272] 127.0.0.1 - - [projectname.localhost/sid#5579881cec50][rid#5579883c5440/initial] [perdir /srv/http/projectname/webroot/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'something/404'
[Fri Oct 02 06:00:00.919761 2020] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 80730] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:33272] 127.0.0.1 - - [projectname.localhost/sid#5579881cec50][rid#5579883c5440/initial] [perdir /srv/http/projectname/webroot/] rewrite 'something/404' -> 'index.php'
[Fri Oct 02 06:00:00.919773 2020] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 80730] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:33272] 127.0.0.1 - - [projectname.localhost/sid#5579881cec50][rid#5579883c5440/initial] [perdir /srv/http/projectname/webroot/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /srv/http/projectname/webroot/index.php
[Fri Oct 02 06:00:00.919784 2020] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 80730] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:33272] 127.0.0.1 - - [projectname.localhost/sid#5579881cec50][rid#5579883c5440/initial] [perdir /srv/http/projectname/webroot/] strip document_root prefix: /srv/http/projectname/webroot/index.php -> /index.php
[Fri Oct 02 06:00:00.919793 2020] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 80730] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:33272] 127.0.0.1 - - [projectname.localhost/sid#5579881cec50][rid#5579883c5440/initial] [perdir /srv/http/projectname/webroot/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Fri Oct 02 06:00:00.919839 2020] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 80730] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:33272] 127.0.0.1 - - [projectname.localhost/sid#5579881cec50][rid#5579883b8010/initial/redir#1] [perdir /srv/http/projectname/webroot/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/http/projectname/webroot/index.php -> index.php
[Fri Oct 02 06:00:00.919851 2020] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 80730] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:33272] 127.0.0.1 - - [projectname.localhost/sid#5579881cec50][rid#5579883b8010/initial/redir#1] [perdir /srv/http/projectname/webroot/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'index.php'
[Fri Oct 02 06:00:00.919868 2020] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 80730] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 127.0.0.1:33272] 127.0.0.1 - - [projectname.localhost/sid#5579881cec50][rid#5579883b8010/initial/redir#1] [perdir /srv/http/projectname/webroot/] pass through /srv/http/projectname/webroot/index.php
```

Instead for the NOK the access.log looks like this:

```
projectname.localhost 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Oct/2020:06:00:00 +0000] "GET /error/404 HTTP/1.1" 404 1131
```

and the error.log does not contain anything.

So maybe you have an idea why this .htaccess is not fired only if using "error" in the URL path and with VirtualDocumentRoot?

Thank you!

Comment: Rarely I come across a question so detailed and so well defined ++

Comment: Do you have any file or directory named `/error` anywhere in project path or alias path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that it only occurs if I enter /error/something in the URL and the hint of @anubhava leaded me to inspect everything what happens in the Apache background. And I really found the reason.

Before using Apache on Arch Linux I used Ubuntu. There it was working and so I compared all files.
Both versions have a configuration file for custom error pages.

- Ubuntu: /etc/apache2/conf-available/localized-error-pages.conf
- Arch: /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

Both files have a line for an alias for "/error/". In Arch it looks like this:

```
Alias /error/ "/usr/share/httpd/error/"
```

However, for Ubuntu the line is commented and therefore not enabled. An error alias is also enabled by default in the original Apache files, and Xampp but it is disabled by default in Ubuntu and on my webserver.

Since the configuration is evaluated first the URL http://projectname.localhost/error/something will execute the alias and in the target directory there is neither a .htaccess file nor a file or directory called "something". So the result is an error page. The .htaccess file in my webroot directory is not evaluated because the server does not access the directory.

I know from my webserver that I cannot change the Apache configuration itself but only implement a .htaccess file.

So the **best solution** (to avoid future conflicts) is to **use only directory names which are not used in any default alias.** I checked the default configuration files for different Apache packages and these are some of the default aliases:

- cgi-bin
- cgi-pub
- doc
- error
- icons
- manual
- uploads

Hope this information can help someone else too.